# Update join model in has_many through association, using the two other models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've read through many other topics here ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182428/rails-nested-form-with-has-many-through-how-to-edit-attributes-of-join-model), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087201/nested-form-and-has-many-through), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087201/nested-form-and-has-many-through)...) but none really solved my problem.

Here are my **3** models.

```
User
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :accounts, :through => :memberships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
end

Account
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
end

Membership
  attr_accessible :account_id, :url, :user_id
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user
end
```

As you can see, my join model **Membership** has an additional attribute: `:url`.

In my **Accounts** table, I store names of online services, such as GitHub, Stack Overflow, Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn.. I have **9** in total. It's a fixed amount of accounts that I don't tend to update very often.

In my **User** form, I'd like to create this:

[image: User nested form]

The value entered in any of these field should be submitted in the **Memberships** table only, using 3 values:

- `url` (the value entered in the text field)
- `user_id` (the id of the current user form)
- `account_id` (the id of the related account, e.g. LinkedIn is '5')

I have tried 3 options. They all work but only partially.

## Option #1

```
<% for account in @accounts %>
  <%= f.fields_for :memberships do |m| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= m.label account.name %><br>
      <%= m.text_field :url %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want to have **9** text field, one for each account. So I loop through my accounts, and create a url field related to my memberships model.

It shows my fields correctly **on the first time**, but the next time it'll display **81** fields:

[image: Loop issue]

## Option #2

```
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag(account.name) %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag("user[memberships_attributes][][url]") %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag("user[memberships_attributes][][account_id]", account.id) %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag("user[memberships_attributes][][user_id]", @user.id) %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I'm trying to **manually** enter the 3 values in each column of my Memberships tables.

It works but :

- displaying both account and user id's doesn't seem very secure (no?)
- it will reset the fields everytime I edit my user
- it will duplicate the values on each submit

## Option #3 (best one yet)

```
<%= f.fields_for :memberships do |m| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= m.label m.object.account.name %><br>
    <%= m.text_field :url %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm creating a nested form in my **User** form, for my **Membership** model.

It works *almost* perfectly:

- exactly 9 fields, one for each account
- no duplicates

**But**, it only works if my Memberships table is already populated! (Using Option #2 for example).

So I tried building some instances using the UsersController:

```
if (@user.memberships.empty?)
  @user.memberships.build
end
```

But I still get this error for my m.label m.object.account.name line.

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Anyway, I'm probably missing something here about has_many through models. I've managed to create has_and_belongs_to_many associations but here, I want to work on that join model (Membership), through the first model (User), using information about the third model (Account).

I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Why to you have has_many users in the account model? I account, e.g. bbxdesign@github.com belongs to many users?

Comment: @Zippie No, it would be 'Account *GitHub* has many Users'. I'm not exactly using that direct relationship between users and accounts, just the join model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the controller, fetch the list of memberships for a particular user

```
# controller
# no need to make this an instance variable since you're using fields_for in the view
# and we're building additional memberships later
memberships = @user.memberships
```

then loop through each account and build a membership if the user has no membership for an account yet.

```
# still in the controller
Account.find_each do |account|
  unless memberships.detect { |m| m.account_id == account.id }
    @user.memberships.build account_id: account.id
  end
end
```

then in your view, you change nothing :)

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using a mix of Harish's answer and yours.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following data-design approach. All users in your system should have the 
memebership entries for all possible accounts. The active configurations will have a value for the `url` field.

```
User
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :accounts, :through => :memberships
  has_many :active_accounts, :through => :memberships, 
            :source => :account, :conditions => "memberships.url IS NOT NULL"  

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships
end
```

Now

```
curent_user.active_accounts # will return the accounts with configuration
curent_user.accounts # will return all possible accounts
```

Add a `before_filter` to initialize all the memberships that a user can have.

```
class UsersController

  before_filter :initialize_memberships, :only => [:new, :edit]

private

  def initialize_memberships
    accounts =  if @user.accounts.present? 
      Account.where("id NOT IN (?)", @user.account_ids) 
    else
      Account.scoped
    end        
    accounts.each do |account|
      @user.memberships.build(:account_id => account.id)
    end
  end
end
```

In this scenario you need to initialize the memeberships before the `new` action and all the memberships should
be saved in the `create` action ( even the ones without `url`).

Your edit action doesn't need to perform any additional data massaging.

**Note:**

I am suggesting this approach as it makes the management of the form/data straight forward. It should only
be used if the number of `Account`'s being associated is handful.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) Will this also populate @account.memberships with the correct :user_id? 2) If he was to store the extra parameter :url, would this work: @user.memberships.build(:account_id => account.id, :url => 'someURL') ? Thanks :-)

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.

Comment: Does @user.memberships.empty? return false if even one membership is present in my Memberships table (for that current user)? So, if I were to add new accounts (such as Reddit or Hacker News), they wouldn't be built, would they?

Comment: You have to handle the edit action to introduce the new accounts

Comment: Added a fix for the `new` scenario.